# best practice for returning 2 different types in typescript function?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have an api function that performs a post and returns Observable of ModelAResponse (interface that i have)

I want two return an Observable of either ModelAResponse or B based on the status returned.

this is my two response models:

```
export interface ModelAResponse {
  res: ModelA;
}

export interface ModelBResponse {
  res: ModelB
}
```

> (ModelA, ModelB are interfaces that placed in another class)

so currently im supporting only one return of model a:

```
public myApiFunc(req: MyRequestModel): Observable<ModelAResponse> {
      ...
this.http.post("my/api/path", req, {headers: myHeaders}),
      (jsonReturned) => status === 200 ? {res: jsonReturned} : undefined);
      ...
}
```

How can I change this func to return either ModelAResponse or ModelBResponse based on the status in the best practice way of typescript?

Comment: Create an interface that both models implement and return an `Observable` of that interface...

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this. Typescript can only type things based on static analysis at build time, what your describing would require Typescript to know the result of your API call at build time, which it doesn't do.

The best you can do is indicate that your API call can return either of your interfaces:

```
public myApiFunc(req: MyRequestModel): Observable<ModelAResponse | ModelBResponse>
```

But that will still require you to figure out if its `A` or `B` at runtime.

Comment: is it possible to do it without waiting for the runtime to figure out the type?

Comment: If your type is determined by the status of the response, and the response happens at runtime, how could you get that information at build time?

Comment: I am also having the same issue, the response is type of  Axios.AxiosXHR<Schemas.IOTPValidatePOSTResponse> | { canceled: boolean}, not able to distinguish...can any body help me .....trying to access like this if (response.data && response.status && response.status === 200) {, getting error on data or status.....